# Creating dynamic and nested routing in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have these routes in a React App:

```
<Route path="/blog" element={< Blog />} />
<Route path="/blog/:slug" element={<BlogPost />} />
<Route path="/blog/search" element={<Blog pageType="search" />} />
<Route path="/blog/category" element={<Blog pageType="category" />} />
<Route path="/blog/author" element={<Blog pageType="author" />} />
<Route path="/soccer-managers" element={<SoccerManager />} />
<Route path="/soccer-managers/:category/:main/:pair" element={<SoccerManager pageType="show" />} />
<Route path="/soccer-managers/alternatives" element={<SoccerManager pageType="alternatives" />} />
<Route path="/soccer-managers/comparisons" element={<SoccerManager pageType="comparisons" />} />
<Route path="/soccer-managers/export" element={<SoccerManager pageType="export" />} />
<Route path="/soccer-managers/reset" element={<SoccerManager pageType="reset" />} />
<Route path="/soccer-managers/search" element={<SoccerManager pageType="search" />} />
```

Basically, I have 3 Components: `Blog`, `BlogPost`, `SoccerManager` and I am reusing both `Blog` and `SoccerManager` by just changing the output depending on the `pageType` and `url`. So for example, `SoccerManager` will filter its rendering in almost all routes depending on `pageType` which comes associated by the `url`. If there is not `pageType` because the url is `/soccer-managers` it will just not filter anything and show all the output.

And this one route is trickier:

```
<Route path="/soccer-managers/:category/:main/:pair" element={<SoccerManager pageType="show" />} />
```

Here I reuse the `SoccerManager` component and if it has a `pageType = show` then I will fetch the url elements, for example:

```
/soccer-managers/comparisons/city/liverpool
```

And just display the output of these 2 in a `comparison` environment.

Now, I want to change it to `Next.js` and the routing works differently and I cannot wrap my head around it. I feel I would need to do something like:

```
--> soccer-managers
   --> index.js (this will be the <SoccerManager /> without pageType
   --> alternatives
       --> index.js (this will be the <SoccerManager /> with pageType = alternatives
   --> comparisons
       --> index.js (this will be the <SoccerManager /> with pageType = comparisons
   --> export
       --> index.js (this will be the <SoccerManager /> with pageType = export
   --> reset
       --> index.js (this will be the <SoccerManager /> with pageType = reset
   --> search
       --> index.js (this will be the <SoccerManager /> with pageType = search
---> blog
   --> index.js (this will be the <Blog /> without pageType
   --> [slug].js (this will be the <BlogPost />
   --> author
       --> index.js (this will be the <Blog /> with pageType = author
   --> category
       --> index.js (this will be the <Blog /> with pageType = category
   --> search
       --> index.js (this will be the <Blog /> with pageType = search
```

Would this be the right way to do it? It feels I am repeating myself so much so any guidance on how to do it properly would be appreciated.

Also, regarding this route:

```
<Route path="/soccer-managers/:category/:main/:pair" element={<SoccerManager pageType="show" />} />
```

I don't know how to create it properly so any advice would be welcome as well.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd recommend looking into [dynamic routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes) and [catch all routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#catch-all-routes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think for next.js routing, if you want to have those variables in the path you will need to nest files for them the way that you are for blog/[slug].js

However, you could alternatively solve this using query params instead in which case you could have just one `SoccerManager` route component. and take in the query options as parameters in the url:

e.g. `/soccer-managers?category=[category]&main=[main]`

These parameters would then be available from the next.js [useRouter](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router) hook like this:

```
const {query} = useRouter()
const {category, main} = query
```

For blog you could do a similar thing like so:
`/blog?pagetype=author&author=[name of author]`

And then inside of the `/blog -> index.js` component you would have access to the `pagetype` and `author` variables from `useRouter` to sort the list of blog articles by.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @madze! How could I translate those query options into the folder routing? So if I have 2 routes now under `blog`: `/blog/index.js` and `blog/[slug].js`, how could I add the other 3 routes for `author`, `search` and `category` ? Thanks!

Comment: @josegp - If these are meant to show a filtered list of blog posts based on the "pageType" then I would probably handle this with query params as well. Something like: /blog?pagetype=author&author=[name of author]. Which would give you pagetype and author as variables to perform your sorting on inside of the blog/index.js component.